# CSS responsive menu - right

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu, responsive-design

I want to move the responsive menu to the right.

Here is an image to explain what i want

[image]

and the code:

http://www.erce.xyz/css/imports/header.css

Comment: Please add the relevant `html` and `css` code.

Answer (score 0):

Add to #primary-menu-trigger next styles:

```
left: auto;
right: 0;
```

As #primary-menu-trigger already have `position: absolute;` it's position your button to right side.

Comment: you beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

**Change:**

```
#primary-menu-trigger,
#page-submenu-trigger {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s ease;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
}
```

**To:**

```
#primary-menu-trigger,
#page-submenu-trigger {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    left auto;
    right 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s ease;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
}
```

Hope this helps,

Tim